# Google API Calendar problems PHP

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, calendar, google-oauth

I'm new to both the google api and stackoverflow, so please bear with me.
So, I have set a this whole setup to get the events out of a google calendar, authorization, keys and all. But, no matter what, I can't get any events back. I hav tried all my different calendars, but none of them give anything different. I also found this handy little tool tied to my service account which shows me when I actually reaches the server, which it always does, and also which of them causes an error. So, it seems like eeeeverything works just fine, but still no events arrive. Is there something obvious I am missing here?
I have tried to make new calendars, new events, new accounts and just redoing everything altogether. I have had help by more experienced people too, but to no avail.

THINGS DONE:

- Creating a google service account
- Creating a project in said account
- Creating credentials for said project
- Downloading JSON:s with keys and ID:s from account and project
- Linking those properly in code
- Creating new events of different kinds in my primary calendar
- Bugfixing
- Making a request for the events
- Bugfixing until no 401 or 404 appears in the log at google
- Still nothing
- Tries to test it at some tutorialpage at google
- Works perfectly
- ???

This below is the code for everything outside of the google library(Also properly installed)
DIR_ROOT is our homemade **DIR** which takes us to the right folders

```html
<?php
   require_once DIR_ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';
   define('SCOPES', implode(' ', array(
     Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR)
   ));

   putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/var/www/html/Tv-Projektet-222309a0ac14.json');
   $client = new Google_Client();
   $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
   $client->setScopes(SCOPES);

   $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);

   // Print the next 10 events on the user's calendar.
   $calendarId = 'primary';
   
   $optParams = array(
     'maxResults' => 10,
     'orderBy' => 'startTime',
     'singleEvents' => true,
     'timeMin' => date('c'),
   );

   $results = $service->events->listEvents($calendarId, $optParams);
   if (count($results->getItems()) == 0) {
     print "No Hermes set for this day. Please update the calendar.\n";
   } else {
     print "Upcoming events:\n";
     foreach ($results->getIgtems() as $event) {
    $start = $event->start->dateTime;
    if (empty($start)) {
      $start = $event->start->date;
    }
    printf("%s (%s)\n", $event->getSummary(), $start);
     }
   }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with one more weeks worth of testing, I found out that a organizations account doesn't work here. I don't know why, but when I used my personal gmail, it worked just fine.